# inserting in different tables through one mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

how can i insert in 3 different tables through one mysql query that is i want to write one mysql query that will insert in 3 different tables.i have basically html form in which there are different tables involved so i will insert data collected from a form into 3 different tables. is it possible if so how ?? if not why ??

for one table

```
  $var1_table1 = $_POST['table1_column1'];
  $var2_table1 = $_POST['table1_column2'];
  $var3_table1 = $_POST['table1_column3'];
```

for second table

```
  $var1_table2 = $_POST['table2_column1'];
  $var2_table2 = $_POST['table2_column2'];
  $var3_table2 = $_POST['table2_column3'];
```

for third table

```
  $var1_table3 = $_POST['table3_column1'];
  $var2_table3 = $POST['table3_column2'];
  $var3_table3 = $_POST['table3_column3'];
```

this is the formate of my variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, PHP's mysql_query() function doesn't support multiple queries (insert, select, update etc), and as you are inserting into different tables with different fields/columns, you have to run a separate query for each.
I don't think there is a way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer**

No you can't insert into more than one table using a single SQL statement.

**Longer answer**

You can achieve it by inserting into table1 and then setting up a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html) on
table1 to insert data into tables 2 and 3 using a [BLACKHOLE table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/blackhole-storage-engine.html) to store your data transiently. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751375/whats-the-equivalent-of-blackhole).

Personally I would avoid this like the plague since it obscures how & where data is being inserted into the database from a given application. A more thorough discussion about this practice can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756617/is-a-blackhole-table-evil).

If I were you I would just write three separate `INSERT` statements in your php application and avoid trying to create a single query that inserts into multiple tables. It'll save you a great deal of pain!

Answer (score 1):

There is **no one standard query that allows an insert into three tables**. However:

- Why do you want one query? Why not just three queries?
- Maybe using a **transaction** can solve your problem?
- Are you sure you *need* three different tables, if they almost represent the same data? Why not one table, and maybe three views if needed?
- Should you *really* need this, you could do this using a **stored procedure**, or even a trigger

Comment: yes i need three different tables.how can i do it through transaction or stored procedure ??

Comment: This is the way to go. Write a transaction that inserts into the many tables. See: [START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html)

Comment: And this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples